# Why does background-color:none not override a specified background color?

Tags: css, background-color

My goal is for all cells in a table to have a background color except ones with the class 'transparent'.  Here is some sample code ([corresponding jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F2kvf/2/)):

```
<style>
    td { background-color: red }
    td.transparent { background-color: none }
</style>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td class="transparent">bar</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Why doesn't the td.transparent cell follow the td.transparent css rule?  When I inspect the element the rule is there, but it is getting overridden by the td rule, which seems to break normal css specificity rules.

I can get what I want by using `rgba(0,0,0,0)` instead of `none`, but rgba is not supported in IE8 and I would like to avoid using an ugly hack if I could.

I'd also like to simply understand why this isn't working the way I expected.

Thoughts?

Comment: `none` is not a valid property value for `background-color`. It is for `background-image`, however, thus the shortcut `background: none` will work.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The value needs to be a valid color, and `none` is not a valid color.  Instead you can use `transparent` (similar to `rgba(0,0,0,0)` but more widely supported).  If that's no good you can always go with `white` or use a more specific rule for the `red` background instead.

Comment: not an answer for most cases including mine

Comment: @stackunderflow this answer is 10 years old at this point; do you have a link to a question whereby this answer doesn't work for your use case?

Answer (score 23):

For what it's worth: you could replace `background-color:none` with `background: none` and it will work.

Answer (score 14):

None isn't a valid color, instead use `transparent`.

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/F2kvf/3/)

```
td.transparent {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Alternatively, you could also use the following:

The reason this works is because it is stating there should be no background in general. It is not referring to a specific color as in the first example.

```
td.transparent {
    background: none;
}
```

[**jsFiddle using this method**](http://jsfiddle.net/F2kvf/5/).

---

As a side note, usage of CSS3 colors (rgba) is not 100% supported. Reference here: http://caniuse.com/css3-colors

---

In addition, I would like to say that **all of this could be avoided** if you didn't set an inital `background-color` in the first place. There would then be no reason to overwrite the original style if this were the case.

Answer (score 3):

The proper syntax (for CSS2.1) is:

```
background-color:transparent;
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-color

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to reset the property to the value from the parent element (`inherit`) or to the default value set by the browser for the property (`initial`)

In my particular case where I needed to override the background color, `background-color: initial;` is what fixed the issue.